# Get value from selected item

Tags: xamarin.android, android-listview

I would like to get value from selected item in list. How can I do it?

```cs
private List<string> selected = new List<string>();`
var list = this.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listOne);
adapterData = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1);
list.Adapter = adapterData;
```

Comment: Could it work now ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you click on a ListView item it doesn't change its state to "selected". So, when the event fires and you do:

```
list.SelectedItem;
```

The method doesn't have anything to return. What you have to do is to use the position and obtain the underlying object by doing:

```
list.GetItemAtPosition(position);
```

### UPDATE

Get you listView item click like below:

```
mListView.ItemClick += MListView_ItemClick;
```

And in your `MainListView_ItemClick` you will get your position as an integer when you do `e.Position`

Goodluck!

Comment: When i try your solution i've got :  cannot convert from 'Java.Lang.Object' to 'int'

Answer (score 0):

You just need listen the item click event,and then get the Value by its position.

For example:

```
private List<string> selected = new List<string>();
private ListView listView;

listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listOne);
selected.Add("AAA");
selected.Add("BBB");
selected.Add("CCC");
selected.Add("DDD");
var adapterData = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,selected);
listView.Adapter = adapterData;
listView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick;

private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = (string)listView.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);//here you could get the value
        Toast.MakeText(this, s, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this, but this code return int position. I would like to get  name(value) of specific list item.

Comment: @LILO What do you mean " return int position" and "get name(value) of specific list item" ?For example,you click the first item ,you will get the value "AAA" ,click the second item,you will get "BBB".Do you want this ?